# Radio buttons: PHP only passing "Other" value

Tags: php, post, if-statement, radio-button, e-commerce

I've borrowed several versions of PHP (from here and other sites) to pass the selected amount in a radio fieldset to a ecommerce gateway, but regardless of what I have tried, it will only pass the amount entered into my "other" field (which is a simple text box).  With any of the radio buttons selected, I get an error indicating that the field is missing or wrong format.  This is my first time using PHP, so any assistance provided at a first-grade level is greatly appreciated! Though the problem is seems to be related to the if else if statement, I included the entire PHP because I don't really understand how PHP works.  Thanks.

```
    <?php 
$x_login = "HCO-ST.-T-902"; //  Hosted Payment Page ID. 
$transaction_key = "6~~xpvR~xMJXN_RkCc99"; // 

if(isset($_POST['amount'])) {
    if($_POST['amount'] == '5') {
        $x_amount = "5.00";
    } elseif($_POST['amount'] == '10') {
        $x_amount = "10.00";
    } elseif($_POST['amount'] == '25') {
        $x_amount = "25.00";
    } elseif($_POST['amount'] == '50') {
        $x_amount = "50.00";
    } elseif($_POST['amount'] == '100') {
        $x_amount = "100.00";
    } elseif($_POST['amount'] == '200') {
        $x_amount = "200.00";
    } elseif($_POST['amount'] == 'other') {
        $x_amount = $_POST['amount']; 
    }
}

$x_invoice_num = $_POST['invoice'];
$x_first_name = $_POST['x_first_name'];
$x_email = $_POST['x_email'];
$CardHoldersName= $_POST['CardHoldersName'];
$x_currency_code = "USD"; // Needs to agree with the currency of the payment page
srand(time()); // initialize random generator for x_fp_sequence
$x_fp_sequence = rand(1000, 100000) + 123456;
$x_fp_timestamp = time(); // needs to be in UTC. Make sure webserver produces UTC

// The values that contribute to x_fp_hash 
$hmac_data = $x_login . "^" . $x_fp_sequence . "^" . $x_fp_timestamp . "^" . $x_amount . "^" . $x_currency_code;
$x_fp_hash = hash_hmac('MD5', $hmac_data, $transaction_key);

echo ('<input type="hidden" name="x_login" value="' . $x_login . '">' );
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="x_amount" value="' . $x_amount . '">' );
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="x_fp_sequence" value="' . $x_fp_sequence . '">' );
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="x_fp_timestamp" value="' . $x_fp_timestamp . '">' );
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="x_fp_hash" value="' . $x_fp_hash . '" size="50">' );
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="x_currency_code" value="' . $x_currency_code . '">');
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="x_invoice_num" value="' . $x_invoice_num . '">');
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="x_first_name" value="' . $x_first_name . '">');
echo ('<input type="hidden" name="x_email" value="' . $x_email . '">');
?>
<input type="hidden" name="x_show_form" value="PAYMENT_FORM"/>

</form>
```

HTML

```
<fieldset name="amount">
<legend><h3>Amount**</h3></legend>
<hr class="hr">
<p style="margin:0">
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="5" checked="checked"> $5.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="10"> $10.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="25"> $25.00<br>
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="50"> $50.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="100"> $100.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="200"> $200.00
</p>
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="other"><span style="text-decoration: underline">Other Amount:  </span>
<input name="amount" type="text" style="width:100%">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: What is the method on your form tag? GET or POST?

Comment: looking like post as by post value is coming as "other", but obviously should be mentioned.

Comment: Since I'm a rookie, I can't answer the question, but wanted to avoid wasting everyone's time.  So here's my solution:

I don't exactly understand why, but the solution was to change the "name" of the "other" text field in HTML so that it isn't included as part of the original array.  I changed the name of the text field to "otheramount", but left the "other" radio button as part of the array.

In PHP, I changed the last elseif statement to reflect that if "other" radio button is selected, then POST the "otheramount" text field.

Comment: It is POST...sorry, would have provided that if I understood it's value/importance.

Comment: I will post the revised HTML and PHP when it will let me (after 8 hour cool-down period).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your html-code:

```
<fieldset name="amount">
<legend><h3>Amount**</h3></legend>
<hr class="hr">
<p style="margin:0">
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="5" checked="checked"> $5.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="10"> $10.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="25"> $25.00<br>
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="50"> $50.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="100"> $100.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="200"> $200.00
</p>
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="other"><span style="text-decoration: underline">Other Amount:  </span>
<input name="amount" type="text" style="width:100%">
</fieldset>
```

Last html-element with the same name (amount) as previous is always used and in this case it is of type text. (It "overrides" the previous radio-buttons)

If you change the name of the text-field you would get the value of the selected radio-button when form is submitted instead.

Try something like:

```
<fieldset name="amount">
<legend><h3>Amount**</h3></legend>
<hr class="hr">
<p style="margin:0">
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="5" checked="checked"> $5.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="10"> $10.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="25"> $25.00<br>
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="50"> $50.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="100"> $100.00
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="200"> $200.00
</p>
<input name="amount" type="radio" value="other"><span style="text-decoration: underline">Other Amount:  </span>
<input name="otherAmount" type="text" style="width:100%">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your last text field name. This name should not be same as radio names.